# Generate random alphabet or glyphs?

Tags: writing-systems

Is there a good program for generating a new alphabet or set of glyphs?

I found this which is a good start:

https://github.com/hmltn2/glyphgen/blob/master/script.js

https://undefinist.com/glyphgen/

I think it was part of a school project but the quality is excellent.

[image]

Or using AI? https://towardsdatascience.com/alphabet-gan-ai-generates-english-letters-589637068808

Comment: Hello, you might consider copying most of your question post into an answer for your question. Other people will still be able to answer, too.

Comment: Thanks. I might try to focus on an answer explaining the programming a bit more (when I understand it myself). I’m tryna understand Bézier curves a bit better, via JavaScript, and also “point groups”, using group theory to generate unique sequences of shapes. There’s this cool problem called the “Thomson problem” where you find the length between N equally distributed points in M dimensions. And you can also generate patterns as an optimization problem based on multiple constraints / cost functions using genetic algorithms or something called “annealing” Ill be learning next. Can do a write-up

Comment: Also the cognition of glyphs really interests me, how the mind parses, receives, processes, follows the shape, of a glyph. There was a painter Paul Klee who developed a whole kind of theory of visual “grammar” I think, it’s fascinated me for a long time, to know or understand it better.

Comment: Sure. Sounds like you'd be interested to make yourself a bibliography and post it as an answer.

Comment: What properties do the glyphs need to have?

Answer (score 2):

You can pick the brains of AI art generators for styles and make variations. The one I tried for the purposes of answering this question couldn't do real writing correctly, which was good.

Here are some prompts, styles I tried at https://dream.ai/create

a scroll with strange writing, nightly v2
[image: a scroll with strange writing, nightly v2]

an unknown alphabet, in the style buliojourney v2
[image: an unknown alphabet, in the style buliojourney v2]

a sentence in Indus valley script, realistic
[image: a sentence in Indus valley script, realistic]

a sentence in Maya writing, realistic
[image: a sentence in Maya writing, realistic]

a sentence in Mongolian writing, buliojourney v2
[image: a sentence in Mongolian writing, buliojourney v2]

Comment: Wow. I’m blown away. I was exploring “point groups” in group theory, and Bézier curves, and genetic algorithms - like, algorithms to produce forms as sequences, possibly under constraints. I had forgotten about free-form asemic writing, (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asemic_writing), which Dream.ai reminds me of